# Encapsulating term for 'kind of class member' (e.g. field, property, method, etc.)

Tags: c#

[This page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/members) defines a list of "the kinds of members a class or struct may contain". But is there a more concise or technical term for "kind of member"? Member kind?
 Member type?

In other words, assuming you had the following declaration:

```
private string name;
```

how would you complete the following table?

```
Name  = name
Type  = string
Scope = private
?     = field
```

Comment: MemberType seems reasonable. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.membertypes(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Ooh, that's interesting. I can imagine it would be confusing when in conversation though.

Comment: You say _table_, you want to store it in database? Otherwise, you could use a single [`MemberInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.memberinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) instance.

Comment: No, that's just a table of information.

Comment: In addition to @mjwills The `MemberType` is property/field/constructor/whatever, while the type that that member may have (applies only for properties, fields and methods), is their `PropertyType`, `FieldType` or `ReturnType` respectivly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There´s the abstract base-class [`MemberInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.reflection.memberinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) that defines most of those terms. E.g. there´s the `MemberType`, which indicates if a member is a [constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.reflection.constructorinfo(v=vs.110).aspx), a [method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.reflection.methodbase(v=vs.110).aspx), an [event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.reflection.eventinfo(v=vs.110).aspx), a [property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) or whatever.

Furthermore some derived classes also have some kind of a datatype. E.g. if your member is a method it has a `ReturnType`, while properties have a `PropertyType` and fields a `FieldType`. However a constructor for example has no type. An event on the other side has an `EventHandlerType`, that will return the delegate-type.

The scope applies to the `IsPublic`, `IsAssembly` and `IsPrivate`-properties. However those are only defined for fields and methods.

Having said this the most common terms I´m aware of are those:

> (Member-)Name
>   MemberType: constructor, method, event ...
>   DataType: string, int, ...
>   Scope: private, public, ...

However there´s no single *technical* term for each of them, as depending on the `MemberType` the other terms may have slightly different meanings.

Comment: Thanks. I was shopping there was going to be some funky technical term for it, like “Yes, that’s called a ‘cromulence’”, but apparently not. Member Type will have to do.

Comment: Obviously I meant "hoping", not "shopping". Sigh.